# React-native useRef value is giving undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use useRef on my TextInput like this:

```
   <TextInput
            ref={commentRef}
            defaultValue={`${postComment}`}
            placeholder={
              addLinkToArticleStatus
                ? 'Attach link to an existing article'
                : 'Comment or ask specific question'
            }
            placeholderTextColor="gray"
          />
```

I have function which shall read the value from the `ref`. And for now I am doing it like this

```
const addNewComment = () => {
    console.log('--commentRef--', commentRef.current.value);
  };
```

But It is always giving me undefined and I don't understand why. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialize it with null. i.e:

```
const commentRef = React.useRef(null);
```

Or use createRef:

```
const commentRef = React.createRef();
```

Comment: Oh my god createRef helped, thank you very much!!! I will accept your answer in 8 minutes